# Using webgl to render high bit-depth textures to the screen

Tags: colors, webgl, color-space, webgl2

Our project uses images with bit depths higher than 8 bits, typically 10 bit. These are stored with 16bit PNGs, with P3 colorspace (so 1024 colors per channel).

I am trying to show these images in a browser using WebGL2. So far having no luck. I know Chrome can do it as I have some test images which reveal an extended colour range on my Macbook's retina screen (but not on an 8bit, external monitor).

Here's the test image: https://webkit.org/blog-files/color-gamut/Webkit-logo-P3.png (Source: https://webkit.org/blog/6682/improving-color-on-the-web/)

If you're using an 8 bit screen and hardware, the test image will look entirely red. If you have a high bit depth monitor, you'll see a faint webkit logo. Despite my high bit depth monitor showing the logo detail in Chrome, a WebGL quad with this texture applied looks flat red.

My research has shown that WebGL/OpenGL does offer support for floating point textures and high bit depth, at least when drawing to a render target.

What I want to achieve is simple, use a high bit depth texture in WebGL, applied to an on-screen quad. Here's how I am loading the texture:

```
var texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + 0);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

// Store as a 16 bit float
var texInternalFormat = gl.RGBA16F;
var texFormat = gl.RGBA16F;
var texType = gl.FLOAT;

var image = new Image();
image.src = "10bitTest.png";
image.addEventListener('load', function() {
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texImage2D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D,
    0,
    texInternalFormat,
    texFormat,
    texType,
    image
    );
    gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
});
```

This fails with

```
 WebGL: INVALID_ENUM: texImage2D: invalid format
```

If I change texFormat to gl.RBGA, it renders the quad, but plain red, without the extended colours.

I'm wondering if its possible at all, although Chrome can do it so I am still holding out hope.

Comment: Unless `RENDERBUFFER_INTERNAL_FORMAT` has more than 8 bits per color (see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/getRenderbufferParameter) and [this](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glRenderbufferStorage.xhtml)), there is no chance of getting this to work.

Comment: `RGBA16F` is not a valid format. The correct format for a internal format of `RGBA16F` is `RGBA` (as you already noticed). The format only specifies the incoming data (`image`), but has nothing to do with how the texture is stored or rendered.

Comment: @Ivella isnt RENDERBUFFER_INTERNAL_FORMAT for rendering to textures? I am just trying to render to the screen

Comment: Note: "extended colours" (as you write) has nothing to do with higher bits (with higher bits we tend to have extended colours, but we used for many years DCI-P3 or AdobeRGB "8-bit data" screens (hardware calibrated, so panels could do much more, like modern good 10bits screens have 14 or 16 bits capabilities) ; so these are orthogonal things). So I'm not sure you are looking the right part of the problem.

Comment: @sipi did you find a workaround for this? By the way, here's the official list of possible combinations of texture internal format, format and type: https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/#TEXTURE_TYPES_FORMATS_FROM_DOM_ELEMENTS_TABLE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK

1. You can not (as of June 2020) create a canvas that is more than 8bits per channel in any browser. There are proposals but none have shipped
2. You can not load > 8bit per channel images into WebGL via `img` or `ImageBitmap`. There are no [tests](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/webgl-conformance-tests.html?version=2.0.1) that data > 8bits makes in into the textures.

You can load a > 8bit per channel image into a texture if you parse and load the image yourself in JavaScript but then you fall back to problem #1 which is you can not display it except to draw it into an 8bit per channel canvas. You coud pull the data back out into JavaScript, generate a 16bit image blob, get a URL for the blob, add an img tag using that URL and pray the browser supports drawing it with > 8bits per channel.

Comment: You said "You can load a > 8bit per channel image into a texture if you parse and load the image yourself in JavaScript"... do you know how this could be done to a frame of a video stream?

Comment: Also, in regards to loading high-depth images into WebGL, isn't this what this Chromium issue (fixed in 2019) is supposed to support? https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=624436#c76

Comment: They hacked that in AFAIK. It's not part of the spec. There are [tests](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/webgl-conformance-tests.html) and AFAIK they don't test 16bit images. What formats a browser supports is up to the browser. For example Safari doesn't support webm or webp (9/2020). And second, if there isn't a conformance test you can count on it not working. The conformance tests test for example an 8bit png's binary data makes it into a texture perfectly, even though by default the browser might color correct. Other formats are not tested AFAIK for binary equality.

Comment: So, while you can upload any image and ask for FLOAT data you can't be sure the data wasn't upscaled from 8 bits and lossy. That is unless they add a conformance test that requires it. The best you could do is test. Make a 1 to 4 pixels float image, upload it as a FLOAT to texture. Render and read the results in such a way that you can tell if data was lost. Same with 16bit images.

Comment: thanks for clarifying it. CG is not really my field of expertise so I'm struggling to read temperature from a thermal camera, which streams frames in 16-bit images. With the popularity of high-depth devices nowadays, it was quite the surprise to find out that browsers are still stuck with 8 bits per channel.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, this is not currently possible. Recent activity looks promising:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1083693&can=2&q=component%3ABlink%3ECanvas%20colorspace